# React/Jasvascript:Dynamic classname setting in map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function to display user dashboard navigation.
This function should set active funciotn to this elem waht is click default is 1 starter element/link.But i get infinite loop.

```
const UserLinks = [
  {
    name: "User Details",
    linkTo: "/dashboard",
  },
  {
    name: "Change Password",
    linkTo: "/dashboard/changePassword",
  },
];
const DasboardLinks = () => {

  const [active, setActive] = useState(1);

  return (
    <SectionNavigation>
      <ul>
        { UserLinks.map((link, i) => (
              <li key={i} className={active === i ? "active" : ""}
            onClick={setActive(i)}>
                <Link to={link.linkTo}>{link.name}</Link>
              </li>
            ))}
      </ul>
    </SectionNavigation>
  );
};
```

When it is executed i get **Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop**.How can i fix it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling setActive instead of passing a function:

```
onClick={() => setActive(i)}>
```

Comment: what a stupid mistake thanks i didnt swa it :)